# Responsive Fonts: Non-supportive Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, viewport

On my website I am using the following `css font-size`:

```
#block-menu .menu {
font-size:.9vw

}
```

The viewport width works great for my responsive website by decreasing/increasing fontsize width depending on screen resolution! It works great in IE 10 and Firefox 30. Yet, what to do with the older browsers that do not support `HTML5/CSS3` ? Example Safari 5 does not support `.vw font-size`.  I have inserted `.9em` as a backup font-size. Works but does not work like `.vw`  font-size. The point of my website is to be a responsive website, including the fonts. Right now the ONLY issue I'm having with responsive website is the fonts.

Here are my questions concerning responsive fonts. 
-If web browser is not `HTML5/CSS3` compliant , do I use something like modernize.js to alert the visitor they must upgrade their browser?
-Just use a `HTML/CSS` friendly font-size for browsers that do not support `HTML5/CSS3` yet?
- Do I have any other options?

Comment: Fall back to something that's *usable*; if the browser can't support all the visual design elements, forget about making it pretty and just make sure it's possible for the user to make use of the page features.

Comment: My fall back font is .em font-size. I guess my question is, should I alert the user to upgrade their browser. The website is for an art gallery.  It really needs to be pretty and usable, which is resolved by HTML5/CSS3 I'm thinking an alert would resolve this for the people who have older browsers?

Comment: Telling users of mobile devices to upgrade isn't very considerate. Some users of older Android phones *can't* upgrade. Give them a friendly (subtle, unobtrusive) message explaining the situation and that you're site will try and deliver the essential content. Don't make people feel bad for having an old phone or for not knowing what a "browser" is.

Comment: Don't tell a user to upgrade.  You can have a fallback stylesheet that approximates the `vw` sizes by resizing fonts at, say..., 3-4 different breakpoints.  Or you can try out a [polyfill](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
 <!-- 
  This is the base buggyfill. 
 -->
<script src="path/to/viewport-units-buggyfill.js"></script>

<!--
  This is the hacks plugin needed for behaviorHacks to work correctly 
  (see below).
 -->
<script src="path/to/viewport-units-buggyfill.hacks.js"></script>
<script>window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init({

// milliseconds to delay between updates of viewport-units
// caused by orientationchange, pageshow, resize events
refreshDebounceWait: 250,

// IE9, IE10 workaround for viewport units allowing vmin/vmax.
behaviorHack: true,

// IE9, IE10 workaround for viewport units allowing Safari for iOS <=
// use vmax.
contentHack: true,

// provide hacks plugin to make the behaviorHack property work correctly.
hacks: window.viewportUnitsBuggyfillHacks

});</script>
```

**Source:** http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/09/24/fixing-cross-browser-issues-with-css3-viewport-units-in-ie9-and-safari-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

If the browser doesn't support something your trying to use and you can't work around it then yes you should detect the useragent string and alert the user that their browser is not supported.

Example for mobile browsers:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ){
alert("Not supported"); // or other prettier alert    
}
```

And here is a list of UserAgent Strings for browsers: 
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/

Otherwise just fall back to something that is supported

Comment: Why notified by device and not browser support for HTML5/CSS3? People still use older browsers on non-mobile devices that do not support html5/css3.

Comment: This is just an example that I had, to detect mobile browsers. using this you could test for any browser that doesn't support html5 and css3